# Show only the first 10 cells in a UITableView

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

Is there any way to show only the first 10 cells in a UITableView? I have a UITableView filled from a XML file, and i only want to show the first 10 cells. The problem is that the UITableView has multiple sections and rows in those sections. The number of rows and sections is different per user.

Is it possible to either hide the rest of the cells or do not show them in the first place (e.g. by not adding them in cellForRowAtIndexPath), i tried to have a counter in cellForRowAtIndexPath that + 1's every time the cellForRowAtIndexPath method was called. I NSLog'ed the counter and it got really big, up till 80, and i did not even had 30 cells in the UITableView.

Thanks!

**Edit:**
The problem is that every time you scroll a UITableView cellForRowAtIndexPath gets called every time you scroll past a indexPath (for the same indexPath), so a counter has no effect.

**Edit 2:**
I figured it wouldn't work, so i modified my XML file to have a counter in the file, now i can check if the counter is larger than 10 from the xml file and check on that to modify the cells in cellForRowAtIndexPath.

Comment: Which 10 rows?  The first 10 across all sections or 10 per section?

Comment: The first 10 across all sections.

Answer (score 5):

You can limit the number of rows that "get loaded" by changing the return value in `- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section`.

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
       return 10; 
}
```

This away `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`will only be called 10 times.

**About your counter:** (you're doing it wrong probably)

Did you declared it as `NSInteger *somensint;` ?

NSInteger is a primitive, not an object! What you are really doing is incrementing the memory address that the NSInteger* is pointing at. Since NSInteger is 4 bytes long, each time you increment it the compiler assumes that, since it's a pointer, you want to jump ahead to the next NSInteger in memory which is why you are getting multiples of 4. Just remove the `*` when you are declaring NSInteger and you should be all set.

Comment: This won't work, because then it will show 10 rows in every section, i want 10 cells in total.

Comment: @Terwanerik you need to do the math... Or limit your data source somehow.

Comment: I did do the counter right, just every time you scroll the UITableView the non visible UITableViewCells are removed from the UITableView. I also tried doing a for loop for all the subviews inside a UITableView, but because all the non-visible views are removed from the UITableView that also did not work..

Answer (score 1):

These are the 2 methods you want to implement. This will let you restricted the number of sections and rows in your tableview without having to manipulate your xml data.

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

Comment: Agree. Just process your xml into a variable that is an array of arrays. The outer array represents each section, and each section array has an array of records corresponding to your cells.

Stop filling up this array of arrays when you reach 10. Then in the two methods above you simply show all available sections and rows in the variable you created. Job done